# make table with foreach and for work in same time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

here I would like to make a table where there number of rows will automatically be made in accordance with the data in `$ kosts-> stock_room`. and then there is also I want to make the data directly arranged with the data I have on the table `residents` by room number, so if i have data in table 'residents' with room number `10` its will fill the table with row `10`.

here my code :

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th width="10%">Action</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Kost</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            @foreach($posts as $row)
            @for($i=1;$i<=$kosts->stock_room;$i++) 
            <tr>
            <td>                
            <a title='Edit Data' class='btn btn-xs btn-warning' href='{{ url("resident/edit/$i") }}'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>
            <a title='Delete Data' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' href='{{ url("resident/delete/$i") }}' onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')"><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>                      
            </td>
            <td>{{$i}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>   
            @endfor
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </table>
```

have someone can help me, to make my code can work exactly like I want?

my wrong result now :
in there my data its always looping

[image]

its should be like this : (in there i only make 10 row)

[image: should be]

data in my table :

[image: table]

for example in there i have data with room number `9` so my table with number `9` its fill with data from database with room number `9`

and iam sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your foreach loop, which creates `<tr>`s, is inside a `<tr>`; it should be inside a `<tbody>` instead. And the first `<tr>` (that has `<th>`'s) should be inside a `<thead>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@foreach($posts as $row)
@for($i=1;$i<=$kosts->stock_room;$i++)

<tr>
..... // Put <tr> inside loop so that it can generate a new table row for each iteration
</tr>

@endfor
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have added your tr in wrong location as have not shown any desired structure as a assumption i have made a correction please try with this code :

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th width="10%">Action</th>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Kost</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
            </tr>        
@foreach($posts as $row)
            <tr>

                @for($i=1;$i<=$kosts->stock_room;$i++) 
                <td>                
                <a title='Edit Data' class='btn btn-xs btn-warning' href='{{ url("resident/edit/$i") }}'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>
                <a title='Delete Data' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' href='{{ url("resident/delete/$i") }}' onclick="return confirm('sure to delete ?')"><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>                      
                </td>
                <td>{{$i}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
                <td></td>
                @endfor
            </tr>
                @endforeach
        </table>
```

if its not help then please put the dump of your arrays and desired structure you want to display